# How do I add weights to edge labels in a directed graph created using python igraph?

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, directed-graph, weighted-graph

I'm starting to use python `igraph` in combination with `networkx` as the former has implementations of very recent advances in `network community detection`.

For now I'm simply starting with 
a weighted, nonsymmetric adjacency matrix and dictionary of node labels. I create a directed graph, G, in `networkx`, which I then converted to an `igraph` `graph, g`, and plotted the result in `igraph` with labelled nodes.

```
import numpy as npy
import networkx as nx
import igraph as ig

# Create adjacency matrix, A, and corresponding directed graph in networkx
A=npy.matrix([[4,7,7,0,0],[3,0,6,0,0],[7,6,0,2,1],[0,0,2,0,4],[0,0,1,4,0]])
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# Dictionary of node labels, simply 'A', 'B', ...'E' for this example
labels_dict={0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}
labels=list(labels_dict.values())

# Convert networkx graph to igraph
nx.write_graphml(G,'graph.graphml')
g = ig.read('graph.graphml',format="graphml")

# Plot directed graph using igraph with labeled vertices, 
ig.plot(g,vertex_label =  labels)
```

This creates the desired graph, but I'd like to know the most efficient means for `labelling` the `edges` with their corresponding weights.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ig.plot(g,vertex_label =  labels,vertex_label_size = 10, vertex_size = 20 
,edge_label = [edge for edge in g.es['weight']],edge_width = [.25*edge for edge 
in g.es['weight']])
```

Arcs can make it difficult to see which weight is associated each edge, which can be addressed by adding the option edge_curved=0.